# STM32 USB Unreliable compilation with GCC '-Os'

Tags: gcc, arm, usb, volatile, stm32

I've noticed some really odd behaviour in my software. It's taken literally months to track down.

I'm using ST's USB Virtual COM Port example code as part of my project, and occasionally the binary that is produced just totally fails to work when compiling with `-Os`. If I change something unrelated then suddenly it'll spring back to life - and compiling without `-Os` everything always works perfectly.

I tracked it down to USB initialisation code that causes an interrupt handler to be called repeatedly. The code is this:

```
#define     __IO    volatile  
#define RegBase  (0x40005C00L)  /* USB_IP Peripheral Registers base address */
#define CNTR    ((__IO unsigned *)(RegBase + 0x40))
#define ISTR    ((__IO unsigned *)(RegBase + 0x44))
#define _SetCNTR(wRegValue)  (*CNTR   = (uint16_t)wRegValue)
#define _SetISTR(wRegValue)  (*ISTR   = (uint16_t)wRegValue)

  _SetISTR(0); // Clear all pending interrupts
  wInterrupt_Mask = IMR_MSK; // 7168
  _SetCNTR(wInterrupt_Mask); // enable interrupts for WKUP/RESET/SUSP
```

This would be fine, but GCC (through many different versions, although 4.8.4 at the moment) produces this code:

```
r1 = 7168
r2 = 0x40005c44 (USB_ISTR)
r3 = 0x40005c40 (USB_CNTR)
r4 = 0
   14b42:   6019        str r1, [r3, #0]    ; USB_CNTR = 7168
   14b44:   490b        ldr r1, [pc, #44]   ; r1 = &wInterrupt_Mask
   14b46:   6014        str r4, [r2, #0]    <--------------- hangs here - USB_ISTR = 0 (USB_ISTR)
```

So these statements are in **totally the wrong order**, and it screws everything up. Both registers are even marked as volatile!

Even if I do this:

```
  _SetISTR(0); // Clear all pending interrupts
  _SetISTR(0);
  _SetISTR(0);
  _SetISTR(0);
  _SetISTR(0); // I really mean it GCC
  wInterrupt_Mask = IMR_MSK; // 7168
  _SetCNTR(wInterrupt_Mask); // enable interrupts for WKUP/RESET/SUSP
```

I get this:

```
   12d60:   601c        str r4, [r3, #0]
   12d62:   6011        str r1, [r2, #0] ; CNTR
   12d64:   601c        str r4, [r3, #0]
   12d66:   601c        str r4, [r3, #0]
   12d68:   601c        str r4, [r3, #0]
   12d6a:   601c        str r4, [r3, #0]
```

So while it fixes the problem, GCC has still re-ordered the write in a totally bizarre way (for no gain), and I'm not totally certain that it won't decide to set CNTR first at some point in the future.

So - why has GCC done this, and what can I do to avoid it? Obviously arbitrary re-ordering of register writes on an embedded system is pretty bad news. Is there a nice way to fix it in this case, and is there a way to be sure that it's not re-ordering writes anywhere else?

thanks!

Comment: Ok, so it seems you can add `asm volatile ("" : : : "memory");` between writes, but I still don't get it. Another post states 'GCC is forbidden from reordering volatile loads and store memory accesses with respect to each other' so could this be a compiler bug?

Comment: Please see [Nine ways to break your systems code using volatile](http://blog.regehr.org/archives/28).  Personally, I am really unsure what the 'C' standard zealots might say about this.  Probably they would argue for days and you would have no clear answer.  **Note:** that `volatile unsigned *` is different than `unsigned * volatile`.  It would be nice to see that **post** for the devilish details.  Why not put the *barrier* and move on?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have anything like `#define volatile /* nothing */` in your code? I have never experienced such behavior as you describe - for the last few years of using GCC and -Os optimization. ST's code is usually a complete crap, so I wouldn't be much surprised if they screwed something in their magic macros.

Comment: I even took your code for a test, and - obviously - it works exactly as expected, all the stores of 0 are before the store of 7168 (optimization -Os). Don't get me wrong, I usually see someone claiming to found a bug in compiler a few times a month, and for the past few years each of these discoveries was a "PEBKAC", not GCC's fault... always.

Comment: Use gcc from here https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded , alternatively you may try this compilation - https://sourceforge.net/projects/bleeding-edge/ (I do it myself and have been using them since 2 years).

Comment: Note: "compiling without -Os" means "compiling with -O0". Like others here, I cannot reproduce what you are seeing. Although I disagree with the "put the barrier in and move on". It should not be needed. I am drawn to Freddie Chopin's theory that something is fishy in your overall build configuration, either discarding the volatile statement or breaking things some other way. At this point, I tend to track down the exact compile command line used when building the affected and replacing gcc -c with gcc -E. Looking at the affected  snippet there tends to be quite revealing.

Comment: Further note (and I'm not trying to be snarky): this is why the [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/) is important. It takes a specific build environment out of context, and if failing to produce one, the culprit has just been found...

Comment: @unixsmurf  By "put the barrier in and move on", I meant that **volatile** is not really the best way to handle this; in fact, I don't think it can ever be correct (for all compilers/cpus).  It would be better to wrap an accessor in inline assembler with a *memory* annotation; this all depends on the larger structure of the code.  If the OP is happy with using *volatile* (which is a mistake imo), just put the *barrier* there.

Comment: @artlessnoise: it can't be correct for all architectures mainly because all architectures do not support memory mapped i/o. And, yes, different compilers can handle it differently. But on ARM, with GCC, this should definitely work. So the fact that it doesn't means that even if this location is resolved, system-provided i/o accessors themselves may not be reliable.

Comment: @Freddie, I'm using the compiler you suggest already. If you check out github.com/espruino/Espruino at eb59683a58b79554a337a5a2fe1735cd44368722 and compile with `WIZNET=1 RELEASE=1 make` you may have some luck at reproducing. I'm pretty sure the volatiles exist as if they didn't, the multiple writes should have been collapsed down.

unizsmurf: I compile with either `-O3` or `-Os`, and `-O3` is fine. I'd love to have a short, self-contained example - but as you say, if I have one I may have the answer already and wouldn't be posting here :)

Comment: It seems that I'm missing some dependencies, because compilations stops immediately with some error in python scripts... `SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'
Makefile:371: *** Unable to work out binary name (PROJ_NAME).  Stop.`

Comment: Could you be using a version of Linux that has Python 2.6 instead of 2.7?

Comment: This is a really old update, but I have the same problem. `-Os` works, without, doesn't. Weird.

Answer (score -1):

I know this is an old post, but I would wonder how was wInterrupt_Mask declared? Was it declared volatile, too? And if not, would that allow GCC to reorder it arbitrarily?

Comment: This is not an answer.